# Cant get reply from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on trying to post to ajax file with jquery and showing result on page posted from. Post gets posted but I get no reply from ajax. Am i missing something here?

form file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Ajax</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myform" />
<input type="text" id="youTyped" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="answer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $('#myform').submit(function(){
        var youTyped = $("#youTyped").val();
        var data = {youTyped:youTyped};
         $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "scripts/ajaxTest.php",  
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
            $("#answer").html(response);
            }
});
});
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

ajax file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['youTyped'])){
    $youTyped = $_POST['youTyped'];
}
echo $youTyped;
?>
```

Comment: form is not a self closing element ? Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/qhLu3/1/ ..........

Comment: Also, if the markup had been valid, the form had been submitted as you don't prevent the default form submit, see fiddle above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you didn't write your form correctly, the elements you want to send are not inside the form.

Second, your js function is not avoiding the form for being sent, so you're reloading the page when submitting the form.

So, to correct it, and get the answer, just change the code to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Ajax</title>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="youTyped" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   <div id="answer"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    // Avoid send the form as a normal request
    e.preventDefault();

    var youTyped = $("#youTyped").val();
    var data = {youTyped:youTyped};
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "scripts/ajaxTest.php",
       data: data,
       success: function(response){
       $("#answer").html(response);
       }
   });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

One last thing. To test it, when you're sending and receiving AJAX, if you're using Chrome you can use the development tools to know if you're sending correctly the requests. Just press F12, and then go to Network tab. If you're using correctly AJAX, you'll see how new lines are added when you press the submit button:

[image]

Comment: Chococroc thank you so much for a complete answer. I have been pulling my hair out trying to find out what was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` on form submit. The form is being submited before ajax request. Also add a closing tag for form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myform').submit(function () {
        var youTyped = $("#youTyped").val();
        var data = {
            youTyped: youTyped
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/ajaxTest.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#answer").html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this code is working:

```
<body>

<input type="text" id="youTyped" value=""/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<div id="answer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
           $('#submit').click(function(){
            var youTyped = $("#youTyped").val();

           $.post('scripts/ajaxTest.php',{"youTyped" : youTyped},function(response) 
         {
                 $("#answer").html(response);
        });
});
});
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Test Ajax</title>
   <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myform').submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
    var youTyped = $("#youTyped").val();
    var data = {youTyped:youTyped};
     $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "ajaxTest.php",  
        data: data,
        success: successMsg,
        error: errorMsg
    });
});

function successMsg(response){
    alert(response);
    $("#answer").html(response);
}

function errorMsg(){
    alert("Invalid Ajax Call");
}

</script> 

</head>

<body>
   <form id="myform" />
   <input type="text" id="youTyped" value=""/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   <div id="answer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An explanation of your answer is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As I toyed with the idea, thought that this would make a good **addition/contribution** to the question.

I added and modified a few things.

One of which being:

- If nothing was typed into the form input field, it would return "You typed: Nothing".

**PHP:**

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['youTyped'])){

    $youTyped = $_POST['youTyped'];

echo "You typed: " .$youTyped;
}

else if (empty($_POST['youTyped'])){

echo "You typed: Nothing";

}

?>
```